# Доступ к идентификаторам ресурсов в Switch

Tags: android

Здравствуйте в `MainActivity` был переключатель по `BottomNavigationView`. Он был реализован через `switch`, сейчас пытаюсь переделать, но в `switch` сейчас похоже нельзя получить доступ к ID ресурса в новых версиях плагина `Gradle`. Как сейчас правильно реализовать переключатель?

Сейчас пытаюсь сделать так:

```
private void changeMenu() {
    bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);
    bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.home);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(item -> {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.favorites:
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FavoritesActivity.class));
                overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                return true;
            case R.id.settings:
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FavoritesActivity.class));
                overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                return true;
            case R.id.myfiles:
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FavoritesActivity.class));
                overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                return true;
            case R.id.home:
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

Comment: Честно, ничего не понял. ID какого ресурса и при чем тут плагин Gradle? Напишите конкретно что не получается, в вашем коде не вижу ни одного идентификатора ресурса.

Comment: Курсор на `switch`, `alt`+`enter` -> Replace 'switch' with 'if'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начиная с версии Gradle 8.0 ресурсы по умолчанию не объявляются с ключевым словом `final` для какой-то оптимизации, что не очень понятно.

Для включения данного режима нужно добавить одну строку в файл `gradle.properties`

```
android.nonFinalResIds=false
```

или же все переделывать в конструкцию `if else if ...`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!