# В switch-case требует const в Android Studio ( Switch-case / OnClickListener)

Tags: java, android

Хочу создать кнопку при нажатии которого, меняется текст. Использую для этого switch, но после того как пишу "case" и R.id.but, компилятор хочет от меня вместо R.id.but константу. Помогите пожалуйста, не понимаю суть ошибки.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    TextView text1;
    Button btOk, btCancel;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        btOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but);
        btCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but2);

        View.OnClickListener Click = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch(v.getId()){
                    case R.id.but:
                        text1.setText("Нажата ОК");
                        break;
                    case R.id.but2:
                        text1.setText("Нажата Cancel");
                        break;

                }
            }
        };
        btOk.setOnClickListener(Click);
        btCancel.setOnClickListener(Click);

    }


}
```

Comment: Что именно пишет? Не свою интерпретацию, а текст, который вам показывается.

Comment: constant expression required

Comment: R.id.but подчеркивается волнистой линией красным и при наведении показывает это

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1551039/%d0%94%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf-%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-switch/1551101#1551101

Comment: Спасибо большое!